# how to apply condition on on each subarray after splitting?

Tags: python, numpy

After splitting array how to apply condiitons to each subarray in numpy

```
b=np.array([
 [450.    ,     447.     ,    448.6499939 ],
 [450.    ,     447.     ,    447.5       ],
 [450.    ,     447.     ,    441.79998779],
 [441.3   ,     440.8    ,    448.6499939 ],
 [441.3   ,     440.8    ,    447.5       ],
 [441.3   ,     440.8    ,    439.45001221],
 ])

cc= np.vsplit(b, 2)
print(cc)
```

I want to apply some conditions on cc like if 0th column is greater than 450 etc

```
[array([[450.        , 447.        , 448.6499939 ],
       [450.        , 447.        , 447.5       ],
       [450.        , 447.        , 441.79998779]]), 
       
 array([[441.3       , 440.8       , 448.6499939 ],
       [441.3       , 440.8       , 447.5       ],
       [441.3       , 440.8       , 439.45001221]])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to find whether:

1. Every value in the 0th column is > 450 (i.e. if the 0th column values are [450, 450, 440], return False)? Or:
2. Whether there exists any value in the 0th column that is > 450 (i.e. 0th column [450, 450, 440] would be True but [440, 440, 440] would be False)?

If you are looking for the first (find if all values are above 450), you could do:

```
all_above_value = np.all(cc[:,0]>450)
```

all_above_value is a boolean which return True if all values in 0th column > 450 and returns False otherwise.

If you're looking to see if any values in the 0th column are > 450, you could do:

```
contains_above_value = np.any(cc[:,0]>450)
```

contains_above_value is a boolean which evaluates to True if any value in the 0th column is > 450.